# При нажатии на кнопку, вывод названия этой кнопки и определенного текста

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Нужно чтобы при выборе определенного набора radio выводился нужный текст

Пример:

```
    <div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="1" name="group_1"></input>Радио 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="2" name="group_1"></input>Радио 2
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="3" name="group_2"></input>Радио 3
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="4" name="group_2"></input>Радио 4
  </label>
</div>
<button id="click_me">Click ME</button>

<div id="text"></div>
<div id="text_button_0"></div>
<div id="text_button_1"></div>
```

Результат должен иметь такой вид:

- Название кнопки из 1-й группы: Название кнопки
- Название кнопки из 2-й группы: Название кнопки
- Название кнопки из n-ой группы: Название кнопки
- Определенный текст, который зависит от выбранных радио.

Желательно чтобы текст перед радио, и текст который получается при выборе кнопок, был в формате html - кода. Также это нужно сделать для любого количества радиокнопок

Comment: я так понял, что вы хотите, чтобы за вас это сделали? Здесь это так не работает. Вы пишете свой код и если что-то не работает, спрашиваете здесь.

Comment: я разве спросил что-то сверхъестественное? код есть, нужна просто jquery составляющая.

Comment: у вас есть html-разметка, а код отсутствует напрочь. вы опишите в чем проблема у вас возникает, что именно не получается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
let textObj = {
  '13': '<span style="color: red;">Text 13</span>',
  '23': '<span style="color: green;">Text 23</span>',
  '14': '<span style="color: red;">Text 14</span>',
  '24': '<span style="color: green;">Text 24</span>',
};
let textRadioObj = {
  'group_0': '<span style="color: red;">Aloha 1</span>',
  'group_1': '<span style="color: green;">Aloha 2</span>',
};

$('#click_me').click(function() {
  let textName = '';
  $('input[type=radio]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).prop("checked")) {
      textName += $(this).data("id");
      let name = $(this).prop("name");
      $('#text_' + name).html(textRadioObj[name] + ': ' + $(this).parent().text());
    }
  });
  if (textObj[textName]) {
    $('#text').html(textObj[textName]);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="1" name="group_0"></input>Радио 1
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="2" name="group_0"></input>Радио 2
  </label>
</div>

<div>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="3" name="group_1"></input>Радио 3
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" data-id="4" name="group_1"></input>Радио 4
  </label>
</div>
<button id="click_me">Click ME</button>

<div id="text"></div>
<div id="text_group_0"></div>
<div id="text_group_1"></div>
```

Получается, что расширяя html и расширяя эти 2 объекта (textObj, textRadioObj) вы можете сделать для n radiobutton груп